# SPFx Tutorial 3: Can't deploy my app after upload

Tags: spfx

I am unable to get anything to happen after I upload my app to the `AppCatalog` library.  Some of the default values I am seeing after upload are:

> Enabled: Yes
>
> Valid App Package: No
>
> Deployed: No

Tutorial 1 and 2 both worked well with no issues.  I am grabbing the `helloworld-webpart.spapp` file in the `sharepoint` folder of my project.

Is there something I need to do after upload to get the **Deploy** dialog to appear?

[Step 3 of Tutorial 3](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld,-Serving-in-SharePoint-Page#step-3-deploy-helloworld-package-to-app-catalog)

Comment: Are you running on a developer tenant (not site collection, but tenant)?

Comment: @PatMill_MSFT I was not.  In the meantime, I have signed up for one and have just gotten this to work there.

Comment: Added an answer to make easier to find the solution - think this has caught a few people out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the SharePoint Framework is in preview and is only available in a developer tenant (you can sign up for a free one). You then need to create a developer site collection in that tenant per the "[Getting Started](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Setup-SharePoint-Tenant)" instructions.